# list out of range in python adjacent numbers question

Tags: python, list

I have a question which is asking to compare 2 numbers in a list, specifically if the adjacent numbers are positive or negatives
However I am stuck on the first part of the question. My idea is to compare the first number using its index with the second number so i+1, but inevitably is goes out of range.

I am missing something here, help is appreciated.

```
my_list=[-1,2,-3,-4,-5,1,2]
for i in range(len(my_list)):
   print (my_list[i])  
   print (my_list[i+1])
```

I have been working on it and this is the full questions

Given a sequence of numbers, find and print the **first pair** of adjacent elements which have the same sign. If there is no such pair, print NONE.

I'm not allowed to use `zip` in this case.

However I cannot do the last bit where it ask pro print none if no pairs are there

```
s = input()
my_list_str = s.split()
my_list = []

for beta in my_list_str:
  my_list.append(int(beta))

for i in range(len(my_list)-1):
  if my_list[i]>0 and my_list[i+1] >0:
     print (my_list[i], end =' ')
     print (my_list[i+1])
     break
  elif my_list[i]<0 and my_list[i+1] <0:     
      print (my_list[i], end =' ')
      print (my_list[i+1])
      break
```

Comment: What will happen if `i==len(my_list)`? Definitely, it will show an index out of range. Use `len-1` in loop like `for i in range(len(my_list)-1)`

Comment: Do you want to compare each number with all other numbers? Or you just want to compare each number with its adjacent?

Comment: the adjacent, it says in the first description ADJACENT

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: Given a sequence of numbers, find and print the first adjacent elements which have the same sign. If there is no such pair, print NONE.
in -1 2 -3 -4 -5 1 2
out -3 -4

Comment: May try this - `for x, y in zip(lst, lst[1:]): # do comparison ...`

Comment: I cannot use zip

Comment: no not in a function. I have edited my question and added the full question with the rest of my code, the only part it is not doing is if it cannot find a pair

Answer (score 1):

Two points:

- Most of the time it is considered *"unpythonic"* to use indices to iterate over a list
- The `for`-loop has the option to close with an `else`-condition: The code in the `else` condition is only executed if the `for`-loop isn't left via a `break`

So, you could try the following:

```
for first, second in zip(my_list[:-1], my_list[1:]):
    if (first < 0 and second < 0) or (first > 0 and second > 0):
        print(first, second)
        break
else:
    print("NONE")
```

**EDIT**: If you *need* to use indices, then you could do:

```
for i in range(len(my_list) - 1):
    first, second = my_list[i], my_list[i+1]
    if (first < 0 and second < 0) or (first > 0 and second > 0):
        print(first, second)
        break
else:
    print("NONE")
```

If you are not allowed to use the `else`-option of the `for`-loop, then you could try:

```
found = False
for i in range(len(my_list) - 1):
    first, second = my_list[i], my_list[i+1]
    if (first < 0 and second < 0) or (first > 0 and second > 0):
        print(first, second)
        found = True
        break
if not found:
    print("NONE")
```

Comment: It is university exercise and it very tedious as the force you to use what they have been teaching,

Comment: @EmiliaDelizia What exactly are you not allowed to use? (See my edit.)

Comment: Prob. missing this `input` part from the OP?  `lst = list(map(int, input().split()))`

Comment: @DanielHao I'd rather use `my_list = [int(n) for n in input().split()]` :) I thought op's remaining problem was to cover the "NONE" case, hence my pointer to the `else` option?

Answer (score 0):

Because you want to `print (my_list[i+1])`
Your list size is 7 -> when i = 6 -> [i+1] = 7
=> my_list[7] <- out of range

Comment: yeah I know that but also the -1 does not solve the problem  


my_list=[-1,2,-3,-4,-5,1,2]
list1=[]
list2=[]
for i in range(len(my_list)-1):
  list1.append(my_list[i])
  list2.append(my_list[i+1])

list one is missing the last number [-1, 2, -3, -4, -5, 1]
list two [2, -3, -4, -5, 1, 2] is correct
how do i create list one with all numbers?

Comment: what you need is:
`list1 = mylist[:]`
`list2 = mylist[:-1]`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below:

```
my_list=[-1,2,-3,-4,-5,1,2]
list_len = len(my_list)
for i in range(list_len-1):
    print(f'comparison {i+1}')
    print (my_list[i])  
    print (my_list[i+1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
my_list=[-1,2,-3,-4,-5,1,2]
list_len = len(my_list)
x =  7 # any positive number
for i in range(x):
   if i < list_len:
       print (my_list[i])  
   if i+1 < list_len:
       print (my_list[i+1])
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 